# SubSonic2.2 Add() not working

Tags: collections, subsonic2.2

I have 2 tables in my DB, Customers, Contacts. CusID is a Foreign Key in Contacts table. I tried the following

```
Dim contact as New Contact(Guid.NewGuid())
contact.FirstName = "Mary"
contact.LastName = "Jane"

customer.Contacts.Add(contact)
customer.Save()
```

Customers and Contacts classes were generated with SubSonic2.2. The contact is not being saved in the DB.

Comment: I still couldn't find any information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the answer is a little bit late but maybe that helps anyway.
Subsonic's Save() method only persists the current object by design.

You can either do:

```
customer.Contacts.SaveAll();
```

or

```
customer.DeepSave();
```

instead.

Comment: The DeepSave(0 doesn't work. Ended up using customer.Contacts.SaveAll();